# Changing the $PATH for _www apache2 user on Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx, ruby-on-rails, apache-2.2, redmine

After several maddening hours of trying to get [Redmine](http://redmine.org) working on Snow Leopard, I finally realized that it was trying to access the system-wide Ruby/Rails install in /System/Library/Frameworks rather than the one I had installed via MacPorts.

I know you can add to the $PATH for _www by editing /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist, but does this stop it from looking in Frameworks and/or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting some of the DYLD_* variables listed in `man dyld`.